# Show values given by AngularJS ng-repeat once clicked from an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to dynamically show the title of a filename once the anchor tag is clicked. Once the anchor tag is clicked, it's supposed to show its filename, then its file at the bottom (given a gdrive link). Showing the file works well, but I can't seem to show the name of the file. Instead of the filename, it shows {{file.name}}, which means that file.name is not being evaluated. (I am using AngularJS to dynamically traverse through and show files and filenames)

Here is the code.

```
<div class="ui two column stackable grid">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="drive-link">
            <h2 class="header" id="filename"></h2> 
            <!-- the filename should be shown here. Value is being passed through {{file.name}} from an a tag below -->
            <iframe name="embedded-iframe" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <div class="ui styled accordion">
            <div ng-repeat="file in files">
                <div class="single-category-component" ng-if="$index==0">
                    <div class="active title"> 
                        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                        {{file.category}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="active content">
                        <a target="embedded-iframe" href="{{file.link}}" onclick="document.getElementById('filename').innerHTML='{{file.name}}';"> {{file.name}} </a>
                        <!--where I'm passing {{file.name}} to the h2 tag on the top-->
                        <div ng-repeat="next_file in files | limitTo:files.length:$parent.$index">
                            <a target="embedded-iframe" ng-if="$index > 0 && next_file.category_id == files[$index-1].category_id" href="{{next_file.link}}">{{next_file.name}}</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-click` to pass the file object to your controller.

**HTML**

```
<h2 class="header" id="filename">{{fileName}}</h2> 
 .............
<a target="embedded-iframe" ng-href="file.link" ng-click="show_file_name(file)"> {{file.name}} </a>
```

**JS**

```
//capture the file properties in the controller function of your ng-click
$scope.show_file_name=function(file){
  $scope.fileName=file.name;
  $scope.fileLink=file.link;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this first set onclick method and pass file name to function

```
<a target="embedded-iframe" href="{{file.link}}" onclick="show_file_name({{file.name}})"> {{file.name}} </a>
```

now in javascript function you can get file name like this

```
function show_file_name(name){
   console.log(name); //this is the file name that you sent form onclikc method
}
```

you can pass multiple values like this

```
onclick="show_file_name({{file.name}}, {{file.link}})"
```

and get it like this

```
function show_file_name(name, link){
   console.log(name);
   console.log(link);

}
```